# group by with empty string

Tags: sql, string, oracle, group-by

I need to make 2 selects and put them together with an UNION. So far, so good. The problem is, for fields with no value, I can put just "0" instead of an actual column, but what do I put for string values? I know that the following example doesn't work:

```
Select field1, field2, 0, 0 from AnyTable
...
UNION
Select '','',sum(field3),sum(field4) from AnyTable2
...
```

So, what do I use instead of ' '?

Comment: Empty string `''` in case of Oracle SQL dialect is equal to `Null`

Comment: Why doesn't it work - what error do you get? Empty strings are the same as null but swapping `''` for `null` would make no functional difference, it would just be more normal and more explicit... Unless `field1` or `field2` are not `varchar2`; what data types are they?

Comment: Oh man, this is so embarrassing.. it turned out I thought I was using one data type when in fact I was using another. I was sure it was a varchar2, but it was an integer (Damn, those misleading field names..). My mistake. But thanks for the comments and answers, it did help me to find the solution. Thanks

Comment: One other comment on your code - know the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`. `UNION ALL` appends the results of the second query to the first query. `UNION` *without* ALL does the same but then also does a DISTINCT of the entire result set. In my experience most often `UNION ALL` is actually desired and `UNION` typically just wastes CPU time on an unnecessary DISTINCT operation. I have made it a habit to use `UNION ALL` and in those few cases where I actually *need* the other, I will write `UNION /*DISTINCT*/` to remind my future self that it is on purpose and not by mistake ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @KimBergHansen, I'll try to use it from now on. I still have a lot to learn, and I bet these tips will really help me out in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

An `zero length string` in Oracle is considered as `NULL`. You need to use `NVL` function to convert the NULL values into some value.

```
SQL> select nvl(null, 'This is null') val from dual;

VAL
------------
This is null
```

**Note** : Take care of the individual `DATA TYPE` of each column in the `UNION`